# Redmine - limit displayed Issue Statuses, by project

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I would need to limit the statuses available when someone creates a new issue, *by project*. So, depending on the project, there will be different statuses available when creating a new issue.

For example, in the following image I have a project "Proj" and I want to create a new issue in one of the subprojects. As one can see, there are more statuses available for me to choose, than I would like to have for this project. I only need displayed 4 statuses out of 7.

Is it possible to limit the statuses available, *by project* ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible to edit the status by Workflow. If you click on Settings and then Workflow and then the Status Transition tab, it allows you to select the Status for a given Status. For example if your issue has a status of New, then you can choose which status should show in the dropdown.

You can manage Issue Categories and Trackers per project but as far as I know Redmine does not allow us to manage Status per project